# Route loading or mounting twice in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When the application launches, the route is being mounted/loaded twice.

Here is a video showing the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgQdM.jpg

This my code:

```
 <Router history={props.history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/event/1234" />} />
        {/*Event */}
        <Route exact path="/event/:eventId" component={Event} />
        <Route exact path="/event/:eventId/friends" component={Friends} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Any idea how to fix it? Help please

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-silence-47ztr?file=/src/App.js:528-884

Note: You can't reproduce the issue on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

well you are doing a redirect in your code

```
  if (!!matches) {
const defaultPathname = `/event/${matches[1]}`;
props.history.replace(defaultPathname); // redirect here
```

}

in your video you are calling `https://47ztr.csb.app/event/1234/friends` which redirect to `https://47ztr.csb.app/event/1234/`